# Javascript extract string from start to 0/, removing anything after 0/

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string which looks like this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG212.jpg
```

I want to remove anything from Pictures onwards so I would get this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = /^.*0\//
var matches = str.match(regex);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could find the index of `/0` and use `substring` to select everything up to that point, like so:

```js
const line = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG212.jpg";

// Get the location of "/0", will be 24 in this example
const endIndex = line.indexOf("/0");

// Select everything from the start to the endIndex + 2
const result = line.substring(0, endIndex+2);
```

The reason why we add +2 to the endIndex is because the string that we're trying to find is 2 characters long:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG212.jpg
                  [24]--^^--[25]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string using `split` method:

```
const myString = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG212.jpg";
const result = myString.split("0/")[0] + "0/";
console.log(result);    // file:///storage/emulated/0/
```

[documentation for `split` method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)